# How to show the Table Without cutting in Oracle

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have Oracle g11 XE  in Ubuntu 14.04, i will to show a table Without cutting ,  for example :

```
      C_ID   A_ID C_PRODUIT
---------- ---------- --------------------
     1      1 real madrid
     2      1 manunited
     3      2 barca
     4      3 barca
     5      2 real madrid
     6      5 barca
     7      5 real madrid
     8     10 juvantus
    10      8 barca
    11      1 chelsea
     9      6
    12      4
```

I do not want to appear so : 
i will to delete the " `------------------------------` "

```
      C_ID   A_ID C_PRODUIT
---------- ---------- --------------------
     1      1 real madrid
     2      1 manunited
     3      2 barca
     4      3 barca
     5      2 real madrid
     6      5 barca
     7      5 real madrid
     8     10 juvantus
    10      8 barca
    11      1 chelsea
     9      6

      C_ID   A_ID C_PRODUIT
---------- ---------- --------------------
    12      4
```

Comment: set PAGESIZE in SQL*Plus

Comment: yes sqlplus !! in ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IN SQL Plus:

```
set pagesize 1000;
```

Your cut will be after 1000 rows.
You can add this line in your glogin file, which is located under $ORACLE_HOME/sqlplus/admin. That way this line will be executed on every new SQL Plus session.